# Build failed with an exception when running app

Tags: flutter

**When running my app I get this error in console** and cannot run the application
The app used to be working properly and suddenly it did that what is the problem?
I don't understand the issue
This is the error from console after pressing run application

Build failed with an exception when running app

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Android resource linking failed
  Output:  E:\Projects\Flutter\labyeeh_store\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:137: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
  E:\Projects\Flutter\labyeeh_store\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:137: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
  error: failed linking references.

  Command: C:\Users\Paymac\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\c7b9bfbf0a2c12e55a72f45c789022ac\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
          C:\Users\Paymac\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar\
          --manifest\
          E:\Projects\Flutter\labyeeh_store\build\app\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
          -o\
          E:\Projects\Flutter\labyeeh_store\build\app\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
          -R\
          @E:\Projects\Flutter\labyeeh_store\build\app\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
          --auto-add-overlay\
          --java\
          E:\Projects\Flutter\labyeeh_store\build\app\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
          --custom-package\
          com.labyeeh.labyeehstore\
          -0\
          apk\
          --output-text-symbols\
          E:\Projects\Flutter\labyeeh_store\build\app\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
          --no-version-vectors
  Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
  Output:  C:\Users\Paymac\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\core-1.0.0-rc01.aar\cb81f74487d3747960ee323a92375a57\res\values\values.xml:89:5-125:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

  C:\Users\Paymac\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\core-1.0.0-rc01.aar\cb81f74487d3747960ee323a92375a57\res\values\values.xml:89:5-125:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.

  error: failed linking references.
  Command: C:\Users\Paymac\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\c7b9bfbf0a2c12e55a72f45c789022ac\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
          C:\Users\Paymac\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar\
          --manifest\
          E:\Projects\Flutter\labyeeh_store\build\app\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
          -o\
          E:\Projects\Flutter\labyeeh_store\build\app\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
          -R\
          @E:\Projects\Flutter\labyeeh_store\build\app\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
          --auto-add-overlay\
          --java\
          E:\Projects\Flutter\labyeeh_store\build\app\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
          --custom-package\
          com.labyeeh.labyeehstore\
          -0\
          apk\
          --output-text-symbols\
          E:\Projects\Flutter\labyeeh_store\build\app\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
          --no-version-vectors
  Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Likely the same cause as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54574235/flutter-and-firebase-execution-failed-for-task-firebase-authcompiledebugjava/54574290#54574290 otherwise check https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27254

Comment: Try updating your compile SDK to 28. These resources were added in API 28.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old flutter projects just breaks in ridiculous ways

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16441

There is a way to fix it as I fixed it in my project here

https://github.com/hungrymonkey/mic_stream/issues/2

Steps: 
 1. Update all plugins and flutter environment to stable 1.0
In your pubspec.yaml add

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"
```

2. Update your android studio to the latest stable
3. open `your_project/android/` folder as suggested by mran-google https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16215#issuecomment-378502866
4. Run build and make all the little fixes
5. In `your_project/android/build.gradle`, classpath grade version should be changed to 3.2.1 https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/17942/files
6. In `your_project/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`, change `distributionUrl` from `https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.x-all.zip` to `https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip`
7. Fix all of your Dart 1 to 2 conversion bugs

I believe these are all the changes needed to migrate old projects on flutter.