# Getting errors when firebase_auth and cloud_firestore with flutter (Tried other solutions)

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

### Steps to Reproduce

I am trying to implement firebase authentication and firestore into my app. A simple login and register page. I always get the same errors (below). I tried rolling back to older dependencies and even undergoing steps to migrate to AdroidX. I have tried other solutions on github and stack overflow, but I cannot solve this problem!

Thank you for the help in advance!

### Logs

#### flutter analyze

```
Analyzing firebase...                                                   
No issues found! (ran in 7.8s)
```

here. -->

#### flutter doctor -v

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, v1.7.9-pre.7, on Mac OS X 10.14.4 18E226, locale en-CA)
    • Flutter version 1.7.9-pre.7 at /Users/SamuelChen/Dev/flutter
    • Framework revision 429726e391 (4 days ago), 2019-06-23 17:01:55 -0400
    • Engine revision 1be3ee342c
    • Dart version 2.4.0


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/SamuelChen/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 10.2.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 10.2.1, Build version 10E1001
    • CocoaPods version 1.6.1

[✓] iOS tools - develop for iOS devices
    • ios-deploy 1.9.4

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.4)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 36.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 183.6270
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.1.1)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
    • Flutter plugin version 35.2.3
    • Dart plugin version 191.7019

[✓] VS Code (version 1.35.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.1.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 10 (API 29) (emulator)
    • macOS                     • macOS         • darwin-x64     • Mac OS X 10.14.4 18E226
    • web                       • web           • web-javascript • Google Chrome 75.0.3770.100 


• No issues found!
```

#### Issues I get when I start the emulator (Debug Console)

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
F/crash_dump32(16827): crash_dump.cpp:460] failed to attach to thread 1544: Permission denied
ERROR: [TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${junit.version}'
ERROR: [TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${animal.sniffer.version}'
/Users/SamuelChen/Dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.7.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebaseauth/FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:8: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
                                 ^
/Users/SamuelChen/Dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.7.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebaseauth/FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:9: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
                                 ^
/Users/SamuelChen/Dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.7.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebaseauth/FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:638: error: cannot find symbol
  private void reportException(Result result, @Nullable Exception exception) {
                                               ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: class FirebaseAuthPlugin
/Users/SamuelChen/Dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.7.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebaseauth/FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:550: error: cannot find symbol
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            ^
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: class FirebaseAuthPlugin.SignInCompleteListener
/Users/SamuelChen/Dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.7.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebaseauth/FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:569: error: cannot find symbol
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            ^
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: class FirebaseAuthPlugin.TaskVoidCompleteListener
/Users/SamuelChen/Dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.7.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebaseauth/FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:587: error: cannot find symbol
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<SignInMethodQueryResult> task) {
                            ^
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: class FirebaseAuthPlugin.GetSignInMethodsCompleteListener
/Users/SamuelChen/Dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.7.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebaseauth/FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:186: error: cannot find symbol
                      public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                              ^
  symbol: class NonNull
/Users/SamuelChen/Dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.7.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebaseauth/FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:445: error: cannot find symbol
              public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GetTokenResult> task) {
                                      ^
  symbol: class NonNull
/Users/SamuelChen/Dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.7.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebaseauth/FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:499: error: cannot find symbol
          public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                                          ^
  symbol: class NonNull
Note: /Users/SamuelChen/Dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.7.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebaseauth/FirebaseAuthPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
9 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':firebase_auth:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 44s
*******************************************************************************************
The Gradle failure may have been because of AndroidX incompatibilities in this Flutter app.
See ___ for more information on the problem and how to fix it.
*******************************************************************************************
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Here is the github issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/35239

Comment: your version of firebase auth is six months old? Did you try updating your dependencies?

Comment: This does look like an AndroidX problem I had back in the day when AndroidX was a problem. Upgrade everything to latest, use `:any` in your pubspec.yaml and you should be fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flutter and Firebase: Execution failed for task ':firebase\_auth:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54574235/flutter-and-firebase-execution-failed-for-task-firebase-authcompiledebugjava)

Comment: @GazihanAlankus I tried `:any`, I still get the same error

Comment: @AaronSaunders Yes I have, I have tried the newest ones, stable ones and using :any

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya I have tried every solution in that issue and other stackoverflow and github issues as well, none helped

Comment: Update the versions in your gradle. Start a new project if need be.