# flutter Could not determine the dependencies ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I'm trying to run first Flutter project on android studio and getting this error again and again :(

```
C:\Users\Pro\flutter_app>flutter run Running "flutter pub get" in flutter_app...                         1.1s Launching lib\main.dart on INE LX1 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Failed to find Build Tools revision 28.0.3

* Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 10s Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        71.5s Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Hope that this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/67459362/12695188

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have all the files inside your build-tools in the SDK.

Find the build-tools inside the *Android -> SDK*.
Inside the build-tools, you can find your version of build-tools, here, 28.0.3.

Make sure there are complete files.
[Files inside the build-tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gS2DH.png)

You can either copy the files from another system, download from [enter link description here](https://androidsdkmanager.azurewebsites.net/Buildtools) or try reinstalling the SDK.