# Trying to Build Apk for My Flutter App But Keep Getting [Execution failed for task ':connectivity:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac']

Tags: android, flutter, dart

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':connectivity:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Was Expecting an Apk build as usual.

Comment: There's probably another error message. please verify that this isn't the whole thing printed out in the console

Comment: Check if this is similar to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65619800/flutter-execution-failed-for-task-connectivitycompiledebugjavawithjavac