# cannot run project cause of connectivity Package with Execution failed for task ':connectivity_plus:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. error

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

I can't  run project and its gives me this errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':connectivity_plus:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Failed to query the value of task ':connectivity_plus:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' property 'options.generatedSourceOutputDirectory'.
> Querying the mapped value of map(java.io.File property(org.gradle.api.file.Directory, property(org.gradle.api.file.Directory, fixed(class org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$FixedDirectory, /home/abolfazl/Desktop/mashrobat/build/connectivity_plus/generated/ap_generated_sources/debug/out))) org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$ToFileTransformer@c383c9e) before task ':connectivity_plus:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' has completed is not supported

I dont know how to fix and I tried almost of  this question and I can not run this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33404552/execution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugjavawithjavac-in-android-studio)  please say How can I fixed I am on dedline
dependency is :  connectivity_plus: ^2.2.0 and flutter version is 2.5.3

Comment: [check out the solution here which has already been contributed to stackoverflow ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67459362/10910438)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have an Internet connection and a suitable VPN to circumvent sanctions

Comment: thanks for respond I have stable net and payed VPN for it but I can't  resovle it