# Getting error while running my flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

Whenever I try to run my Flutter app in Android studio connected with my Android it shows

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':firebase_core:processDebugManifest'.
> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/Users/user/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.17.1/android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml; lineNumber: 11; columnNumber: 12; Content is not allowed in trailing section.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 23s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54574235/10157127) may help

Comment: I tried that one

Comment: can you share the `flutter doctor -v` output

Comment: https://prnt.sc/VkaCebE6yMrS

Comment: you can try `flutter clean` and re-initialize the Firebase with `firebase init`